# using an excel sheet to update other sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a work book using three different sheets. The first sheet is a ‘pending sheet’ where info is input row ‘x’ into columns A thru K, and M. Columns L and N are left blank. I am trying to develop a simple way to transfer the info from the row into sheet two, to the next available row (in sheet 2) if text is input into ‘x’ row column L, and if text is input into row ‘x’ column N it automatically puts it into the next available row in sheet 3.
I was going to simply cut and paste but each the row height changes in the cut from sheet and the borders disappear. I’ve tried locking, unlocking, protecting. Nothing works properly.
I’ve tried recording a macro but it doesn’t automatically find the next available row on the other sheet. I’ve tried cut and paste special….

Comment: Microsoft Excel is not a web app. Your question belongs on [su]. However, before reposting it there, it could use some cleanup. A screen shot of the behavior you're seeing would probably be helpful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about installable software.

Comment: Your question is now on the right site, but it isn't clear.  What is supposed to trigger or direct action and determine the relevant ranges?  What is the actual problem (is the issue just formatting)?